# SQLiteDatabase usage pattern

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I currently use the following pattern when accessing my SQLite database (possibly from different threads):

```
try(SQLiteDatabase db = new MySqliteOpenHelper(context).getWritableDatabase()) {
    ...
}
```

Until now I thought that it was clean and thread-safe, but I got some crashes due to "Database is locked".

Why is this pattern wrong and how should I change it?

Comment: what's MySqliteOpenHelper ? Which part do you think is thread safe?

Comment: @Blackbelt the `SQLiteOpenHelper` part

Comment: @Blackbelt Or the `SQLiteDatabase` part maybe

Answer (score 1):

`MySqliteOpenHelper` is not a singleton. To create a singleton in that class do the following in `MySqliteOpenHelper`.

1 Add a static `instance` variable of type `MySqliteOpenHelper`

2 Add a method called `getInstance(Context)` (body as shown below)

```
public synchronized static getInstance(Context context){
    if(instance == null){
        instance = new MySqliteOpenHelper(context);
    }
    return instance;
}
```

This is thread safe as you will always be using one object.

Comment: But I've read that `SQLiteOpenHelper` is supposed to handle thread safety, isn't it?

Comment: I've never read anything similar, do you have a source?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6675272/569558 : "You shoud use locking-related SQLiteHelper methods to provide thread safety."

Comment: That's saying `SQLiteDatabase` is thread safe not `SQLiteOpenHelper`

Comment: You're right, but then why do I need to handle thread-safety myself if `SQLiteDatabase` handles it?

Comment: You need to use `SQLiteOpenHelper` to open an instance `SQLiteDatabase`. Methods on  `SQLiteDatabase` are thread safe by default. But to open the database you need to use `SQLiteOpenHelper ` which is not thread safe.

Comment: At which level does the "database locked" issue happen? (SQLiteDatabase or SQLiteOpenHelper)

Comment: It happens because you are creating *another* instance of `SQLiteOpenHelper` when one already exists (and has open handle to database). `SQLiteOpenHelper` then tries to open the database but fails because it is already in-use by the other `SQLiteOpenHelper`

Comment: Last question then :) What establishes the db connection ? The instantation of `SQLiteOpenHelper` or the call to `getWritableDatabase()` ?

Comment: `getWriteableDatabase` - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getWritableDatabase()